# Java append newline every n lines

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-interface

```
String[] names = new String[18];
names[0] = "James Raider";
names[1] = "Calm Hain";
names[2] = "Ewds Ashby";
names[3] = "Gedge Taylor";
names[4] = "Hay Fin";
names[5] = "Ian Hilton";
names[6] = "John Coke";
names[7] = "Nathan Dryer";
names[8] = "Jess Maguire";
names[9] = "Jamie Loyal";
names[10] = "Luke Shwinger";
names[11] = "Parrot Tom";
names[12] = "John Clarke";
names[13] = "Steven Mason";
names[14] = "Shing Lao";
names[15] = "Tom Brook";
names[16] = "Arthitus Pint";
names[17] = "Yifan Yao";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    field.append(names[list.get(i)] + "\n");
    for (int u = 0; u < (Integer) number.getValue(); u++) {
        field.append("\n");
    }
}
```

I am trying to add a new line to the output, every `number.getValue()` amount of times. What I'm doing adds it after every line, but I only want it to create it after a set number of times.

---

Example: 3 times

```
Harry
John 
Jake

Amanda
Holly
Sam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `if` statement in your for loop that prints new line after every n-lines of outputs (I believe that is what you wanted, not after n-iterations). Lets say you want new line every 3 lines
Pseudo code:

```
int newLine = 3;
int multiplicator = 1;
for(int i = 0; i< names.length; i++){
  if( newLine == i){
    // print extra line after every 3rd output        
    field.append("\n");
    newLine = 3; //to reset variable to the correct delimiter on each subsequent n-th iteration
    multiplicator++;
    newLine = newLine * multiplicator;
  }
field.append(names[i] + "\n")
// print regular value on normal line during every iteration
}
```

Comment: What is "arr"? for(int i = 0, i< arr.length, i++)

Comment: @Dullah arr stands for array you want to iterate over. So replace it with your desired array name (or list in your case).

Comment: Where in that code would i put the "field.append(names[x])" ? Because right now there is no output.

Comment: I edited my solution to make it more similar to your problem. Now it should be clear.

Comment: Now I am getting it to do what i want, for the first 2 "paragraphs, then it just spits out the rest, if you know what i mean.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, did not debug my solution. now it should work flawless with what I believe is last edit.

Comment: Yes! Perfect! I had been trying for so long to do this. Thank you!

Comment: @Dullah No problem, this is what SO is for. Just be sure to accept my answer as correct answer, so future users with similar problems can refer to it. Have a good one.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you your desired output.

```
for (int i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) {
    // add name to field
    field.append(names[list.get(i)]);
    field.append('\n');

    // every number.getValue() names, add a new line
    if (i % number.getValue() == (number.getValue() - 1)) {
        field.append('\n');
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Upon editing your original post, I saw some formatting was lost in your example. Updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod` to help you out with this. Something like this:

```
for (int i=0; i<names.length; i++) {
    field.append(names[list.get(i)]+"\n");
    if (i%3==0){
        //Do Stuff here every 3rd iteration. 
    }
}
```

Not sure when you want to print but `mod`, `%`, just takes the remainder of the number. Very useful when looping. So in the above example it would only go inside the `if` when `i` divided by 3 has no remainder. So for the following `i`:

> 0 3 6 9 12 15

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually, you first print extra line after 4th iterations and then after 6th (which are just two steps) iteration. So your math is kind of flawed.